# Read in Python a text file to recover the variables defined in there

Tags: python, file

I have a .txt file containing:

```
diccionario = {'1':"whatever", '2':54}
```

I want to read that file inside of a program in such a way that the variable "diccionario" is created in that program with the desired value.

I tried using `exec()` like this but it doesn't work.

```
exec(open("file.txt","r").read())
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what error did u get?

Comment: "but it doesn't work". What doesn't work?

Comment: exec() works when it's used in the console, but not when it's used inside a function. I guess it has something to do with local and global variables but I don't really understand the problem.
If I run this code `def funcion(texto):\n     exec(texto)\n     print(lista)\n funcion("lista = [3,4,5]")` I get an error "NameError: name 'lista' is not defined". Sorry but I don't know how to write code in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If you run code using `exec`, you can access the variables defined in the code like any regular variable:</strike>

```
code = "variable = 'Hello, world!'"
exec(code)
print(variable)
```

This outputs:

```
Hello, world!
```

The above only works in a repl environment. Unfortunately it is not possible outside of the repl. The good news is that you can achieve the same functionality.

Besides the code, `exec` takes two other parameters: `globals` and `locals`. These respectively represent all the globally defined variables and the variables bound to the local scope. These values will be used as the global and local scope during the execution of the code. Their default values are `globals()` and `locals()`, so `exec(code, globals(), locals())` is identical to `exec(code)`.

Normally speaking you can't modify `locals()`, so you won't be able to add variables to the local scope. However, you *can* add global variables:

```
code = "global variable; variable = 'Hello, world!'"
exec(code)
print(variable)
```

The downside is that you have to declare a variable as global. If you can't do that, there is one last option:

```
code = "variable = 'Hello, world!'"
exec_locals = { }
exec(code, globals(), exec_locals)
print(exec_locals)
```

This yields: `{ 'variable': 'Hello, world!' }`

Using this, you can access the local variables defined in `code`

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for your answer. That works for me in the console but not inside a function.

Comment: If I run this code 
`def funcion(texto):\n
    exec(texto)\n
    print(lista)\n

funcion("lista = [3,4,5]")`
I get an error "NameError: name 'lista' is not defined". Sorry but I don't know how to write code in the comments.

Comment: You're right, I didn't test it outside of the repl. I will update my answer